# Upload file to Dropbox programmatically from Android APP

Tags: android, upload, dropbox, dropbox-api

I have an App that downloads MP3 files but I'd like to provide an option to the user to upload the file to dropbox on download completion. I've looked through the API couldn't see how to do it. Is that possible at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use either the Core SDK:

https://www.dropbox.com/static/developers/dropbox-android-sdk-1.5.4-docs/com/dropbox/client2/DropboxAPI.UploadRequest.html

or the Sync SDK:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/sync/docs/android#com.dropbox.sync.android.DbxFile

to upload files from Android to Dropbox.

Comment: could you tell me how I can upload file by using Sync API? I tried `getAppendStream()`, `writeFromExistingFile()` and `getWriteStream()` to copy stream but they don't work.

Comment: The Android Sync SDK tutorial has some sample code to get you started: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/sync/start/android#files

Comment: Actually I have already read it. But the example (Hello & notes examples) only use the text file. I need to know how to upload the binary files (.pdf, .docx...)  I tried copy stream but doesn't effect to dropbox server. You can see my detail here: https://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=108322

Comment: both dropbox links dead :|

Comment: @praveenb This post links to old SDKs that have since been retired. You can find the current Dropbox Java SDK here: https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-java including an example of using it on Android here: https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-java/tree/master/examples/DropboxAndroid

Comment: Could you pls Edit answer, and update with above comment. Thanks