# Dropbox android Intent.ACTION_SEND not working anymore

Tags: android, android-intent, dropbox

Just noticed that saving file to Dropbox with Intent.ACTION_SEND is not working anymore. 
So what can we use now?
I see Dropbox app in selection, when i try to save just creates new file

Comment: try this answer on stackoverflow............http://stackoverflow.com/a/17054290/3678308

Comment: Found some temp solution - remove extra: EXTRA_TEXT

Comment: good.......................

Comment: For reference: https://www.dropboxforum.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206573896-Android-ACTION-SEND-changed-